# submit value of the image with ajax in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

My idea was to ask the user how many forms he wants to be created and then to choose the form he wants to edit, thereafter ask how many elements he wants to be created and the type of them. that's what I have done so far:

```
 <h2>Questions</h2><br>

                            <p>How many questions do you want to be created?</p>

                            <form id="stepsform">
                            <input type="number" name="steps" id="steps" style="color:black">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><button class="button scrolly" name="numberform" id="numberform">Submit</button></li>
                                </ul>
                            </form>


    <script>
        $( "#stepsform" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( "input[name='steps']" ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );
        var posting = $.post( url, { numberform: term } );

        posting.done(function( data ) {
        var content = $( data ).find( "#content" ); 

        $( "#content" ).empty().append( content );
        var uri = "#two";    
        $(location).attr('href',uri);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and that's the script where I stuck, after the images are created via ajax, I want them to be clickable so that the user can submit a value which is behind the image:

```
<h2>Forms</h2>

                             <p>choose the form you want to edit</p>
                             <div id="content">
                             <form id="elementsform">
                             <?php 
                            if(isset($_POST['numberform'])){
                                $i = 0;
                                $formchoice = array_fill($i, $_POST['numberform'], 'Formular' );

                                foreach($formchoice as $key){
                                    echo ' <input type="image" src="formular.png" alt="'.$formchoice[$i].$i.'" data-formularid="'.$formchoice[$i].$i.'" height="100px" width="100px" name="'.$formchoice[$i].$i.'">  '."\t";
                                    $i++;
                                }
                            }
                             ?>
                             </form>
                             <script>
        $( "#elementsform input[type='image']" ).click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formular_id = $(this).data("formularid");
            term = $form.find( "input[type='image']" ).val(),
            url = $form.attr( "action" );
            var posting = $.post( url, { elementsform: term } );

            posting.done(function( data ) {
            var content = $( data ).find( "#content1" ); 

            $( "#content1" ).empty().append( content );
            var uri = "#three";    
            $(location).attr('href',uri);
        });
});
</script>
```

when I click on the image, nothing happens but actually it should submit value which is in data-formularid="" and thereafter go to another questions, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate your click event

```
  $( "body" ).on('click','#elementsform input[type="image"]',function( event ) {                
                    $form = $(this).closest('form');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formular_id = $(this).data("formularid");
                    term = $form.find(this).val(),
                    url = $form.attr( "action" );
                    var posting = $.post( url, { elementsform: term, formularid:formular_id } );

                    posting.done(function( data ) {
                    var content = $( data ).find( "#content1" ); 

                    $( "#content1" ).empty().append( content );
                    var uri = "#three";    
                    $(location).attr('href',uri);
                });
```

Comment: it's not working, the page is just reloaded. the console doesnt show any errors. it should actually pass the value of the clicked image via post to php script

Comment: what do you want to do here? `$(location).attr('href',uri);` where is this location variable?

Comment: location is for forwarding the user to the next section of the questions, im still working on the next section thats the code                           `<section id="three" class="wrapper style1 fullscreen fade-up">            <div class="inner">
<h2>Elements</h2><section><p>how many elements do you want to be created?</p><p id="content1"><?php if(isset($_POST)) var_dump($_POST); ?></p> <form><input type="number" name="elementsnumber" id="elementsnumber" style="color:black"></form></section></div></section>`

Comment: why aren't you using window.location.hash?

Comment: i think location href works better, but anyway the script doesnt seem to pass the value via ajax post method

Comment: when I click on the image, i get the error that $form is not defined

Comment: yes it passes the form but it doesnt pass the value of the image which is in the data-formularid="" because all the images are dynamically created

Comment: you are not passing formular_id  value to the ajax see my updated answer